# Getting fiber bundles from short exact sequences

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, exact-sequence, fibration

Are there conditions that guarantee that a split short exact sequence of groups
$$
1 \rightarrow K \rightarrow G \rightarrow Q \rightarrow 1
$$
gives rise to a fiber bundle
$$
F \rightarrow E \rightarrow B
$$
on the level of $K(\pi,1)$'s?

Any references relating fibrations to group extensions would be appreciated.

Comment: See theorem 11.4 [here](http://www.math.washington.edu/~mitchell/Notes/prin.pdf). The notion of $H$ being admissible is purely topological; if your groups are discrete, a short exact sequence always gives rise to a fibration.

Comment: Excellent - thanks for the speedy reply!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $1 \to H \to G \to K \to 1$ be an exact sequence of topological groups. If $G \to G/H$ is a principle $H$-bundle, then theorem 11.4 [here](http://www.math.washington.edu/~mitchell/Notes/prin.pdf) guarantees a fibration of classifying spaces $BH \to BG \to BK$. This assumption is satisfied if, for instance, $G$ is discrete, or if all the groups involved in the sequence are Lie groups.

Comment: Is there any extra structure on the fibration if the underlying exact sequence of groups was split?